# HighCharts Live Data using mqtt

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, mqtt, livegraph

I am trying to prepare live chart using react and highcharts. I am using `react-mqtt` to retrieve live data and passing the data as props to Highchart component.

The Chart is rendering but, every time the data comes, it's rerendering the component.

My Expectation is, it should flow like a heartbeat graph. but a multi-line heartbeat.

Homepage:

```
            import React from 'react';
            import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet';
            import { FormattedMessage } from 'react-intl';
            import { connect } from 'react-redux';
            import { compose } from 'redux';
            import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

            import Chart from 'components/HighCharts';

            import { Connector } from 'mqtt-react';
            import {subscribe} from 'mqtt-react';

            const MessageContainer = subscribe({topic: 'system_monitor'})(Chart);

            export class HomePage extends React.PureComponent {

            render() {
                return (
                <article>
                    <Helmet>
                    <title>Home Page</title>
                    <meta name="description" content="A React.js Boilerplate application homepage" />
                    </Helmet>
                    <div>
                    <Connector mqttProps="ws://localhost:1884/">
                    <MessageContainer/>
                    </Connector>
                    </div>
                </article>
                );
            }
            }
```

HighChart Component Code:

```
            import React, { Component } from 'react';
            import HighCharts from 'react-highcharts';

            export default class SplineChart extends Component {

                constructor(props) {
                    super(props);
                    this.config = {
                        chart: {
                            type: 'spline',
                            animation: HighCharts.svg,
                            marginRight: 10,
                            width: 700,
                            height: 360,
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'RFID Chart'
                        },
                        legend: {
                            enabled: true
                        },
                        exporting: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            type: 'datetime',
                            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                hour: '%I',
                                minute: '%I:%M',
                                seconds: '%I:%M:%S'
                            },
                            title: {
                                text: 'Time'
                            }
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Heart Beat'
                            }
                        },
                        series: this.props.data
                    }
                }

                render() {
                    console.log(this.props.data)
                    return (
                        <div>
                            <HighCharts config={this.config}></HighCharts>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Improved formatting.

Comment: added code @Colin

Comment: Sample data from my local mqtt server:
x value is TimeStamp and y the data point
[ {"data":[[1524903290174,50],[1524903295176,55],[1524903300182,0],[1524903305185,5]]}] . Data comes every second.

Answer (score 0):

check [accessing-highcharts-api-after-render](https://github.com/kirjs/react-highcharts#accessing-highcharts-api-after-render) and use `addPoint()` to add points dynamically.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    let chart = this.refs.chart.getChart();
    //chart.series[0].addPoint({x: 10, y: 12});

    //below is for demo    
    // set up the updating of the chart each second
    var series = chart.series[0];
    setInterval(function () {
      var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        y = Math.random();
      series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    }, 1000);

  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-highcharts-dynamic-update?file=index.js) demo

Comment: but, the above which you have given is not useful to me, because i need to pass data from mqtt

Comment: `chart.series[0].addPoint({x: 10, y: 12});` means `addPoint` is way of updating chart without reloading the chart you can use in mqtt

Comment: but, when i receive data in highchart component, its re-rendering.

Comment: I am calling mqtt in my index and passing the data to chart component, does it re-renders the whole component? if yes, where can i subscribe to mqtt?

Comment: instead of `series: this.props.data` in config ,initially pass as empty `series:[]`,  and when mqtt is returning data ,update chart with `chart.series[0].addPoint([x,y],true,true);`

Comment: nopes its re-rendering when my props from mqtt changes.. :(

Comment: I have updated the state in shouldComponentUpdate and set return false, so as to stop the re-rendering. Hope it will solve my problem. Thanks for your suggestions.